Why are all the files in my Android Studio project, such as build.gradle, red?

I tried changing the sdk version and there is still a red underline to it. Can anyone please elaborate what is going on?


change project to android then go to fileMenu and click invalidate caches restart then automatic reopen the android studio this would help you



"red" files in Android Studio means that they aren't added to git
repository

green - just-added files, pending to commit (this is the step you
should take now)

black or white, depend on style - already added to repo files,
not changed since last commit (also ignored?)

blue - these are tracked by repo and changed since last commit


if you are just messing around and don't plan to make a repo you can just ignore these colors. repository is strongly recommended for main longer projects
